# List of Students in a Class

Tags: java, list

I would like to create a class for students in a course. The only requirements are: each student should have a first name, last name, and an average of grades. Pretty simple so far.

```
public class ClassStudents{

    String firstName, lastName;
    double p1, p2, p3;

    public ClassStudents(String fn, String ln){
        this.firstName = fn;
        this.lastName = ln;     
    }

    public double average(){        
        return (p1 + p2 + p3) / 3;
    }
}
```

I would like also to calculate the average of the whole class. I was thinking about creating a list of each student and then I'll just divide their averages by the length of the list. I've tried something like `List<ClassStudents> students = new ArrayList<ClassStudents>();` but it's not quite working for me.

Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: How specifically are you using the `students` Array list to get the average? Please provide a snipit of your main method that has your declaration of the array list and your method for calculating the total average.

Comment: Also when you have an issue that isn't quite working it's best to describe your attempt of the solution and what specifically you are seeing about it that isn't correct. Add any pertinent compiling errors or  incorrect outputs and corresponding inputs.

Comment: Please accept the answer which helped you most in solving your problem. It helps future readers. If the answers weren't helpful leave comments below them. So the poster can update them accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Several issues in your code:

The names `p1, p2, and p3` for variables are rather bad because I don't know what they stand for, so you would rather choose some better names. Also is the type dobule a bit weird (not knowing your school system, but in Germany for example you only have 1,2,3,4,5,6 or 0-15 points  which would suit an `Integer` better)

Also is the class name `ClassStudents` not really suitable for what it is. It's a class for one Student, therefore I'd name it `Student`. You usually don't write class before a class in Java because that's more or less implicit.

The list actually works fine for the average:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Student mario = new Student("Mario", "290");
    mario.p1 = 3;
    mario.p2 = 2;
    mario.p3 = 1;
    Student maria = new Student("Maria", "291");
    maria.p1 = 3;
    maria.p2 = 2;
    maria.p3 = 6;
    List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();
    studentList.add(mario);
    studentList.add(maria);

    double sum = 0;
    for (Student student : studentList) {
        sum += student.average();
    }
    sum /= studentList.size();
    System.out.println("The average grade for the students is " + sum);
}
```

Since you're likely to know the grades when you construct the Student object, I'd add it into the constructor as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a static variable counter.  Then in the constructor add 1 to it.

```
private static int count = 0;

public ClassStudents(String fn, String ln){
        this.firstName = fn;
        this.lastName = ln;
        count++
}
```

Just remember to subtract one from the count variable if you remove a student.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate your list of students, take the `avarage()` of each student and divide it by the number of students.

```
List<ClassStudents> students = new ArrayList<ClassStudents>();
double totalAvarage = 0;
for(ClassStudents std: students){
    totalAvarage += std.avarage();
}
totalAvarage /= students.size();
```